# Passing Record id to Apex class using Wire Service from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

---

How to pass the record id to the Apex class. Trying to get the number of contacts associated to a specific account. On the final approval step( process instance work item)the related account is associated to the work item. Tested the Apex class, when i Query i get the results so the Apex class works fine. Console log Hello says undefined.

This absolutely works fine from anonymous when it has a record id. both debug statements return values
Console log shows undefined.

JS:

```
import { api, LightningElement, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/GetContactCount.getContacts';
export default class AccountInfo extends LightningElement {

@api recordId;

@wire(getContacts, { recordId: '$recordId' })
wiredRecordsMethod({ error, data }) {
  console.log('Hello' + data);
  if (data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.error = undefined;
  } else if (error) {
    this.error = error;
    this.data = undefined;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
<div>
    <p>Contact Count: {data}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

Apex:

```
public class GetContactCount {
  @AuraEnabled public integer contactCount {get; set;}
  @AuraEnabled public date activityDate {get; set;}

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
  public static integer getContacts(string recordId){
    GetContactCount getDetails = new GetContactCount();
    List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> pIW= [select id,ProcessInstance.TargetObject.id,ProcessInstance.TargetObject.name from ProcessInstanceWorkitem where id=:recordId];
    id accId =pIW[0].ProcessInstance.TargetObject.id;
    getDetails.contactCount = [Select count() from Contact where accountId=:accId ];
    system.debug('Contactcount'+getDetails.contactCount);
    return getDetails.contactCount;

  }
}
```

Comment: javascript is case-sensitive. 'recordId' property is mentioned as 'recordid'. correct it and try again.

Comment: Removed (cacheable = true) from Apex class modified recordid. neither of the changes worked.@BilalMalik @HR

Comment: Hey, (cacheable=true) is required. since you are calling apex using @wire property.

Comment: if you call apex imperatively (cacheable=true) is not required.

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code.

Comment: Updated. its just the recordId change.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some considerations when you user `wired` configurations

1. **Object Property prefixed with $ is dynamic and reactive.**

   The $ prefix tells the wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as this.propertyName. The property is reactive. If the property’s value changes, new data is provisioned and the component rerenders. Refer detailed documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

   For `recordId` attribute, ensure the component is on a Record page to get the `recordId`, so that the value is set and wired configuration calls `Apex`
2. **Use `@track` to update the template with changed values.**

   Fields are reactive. If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value.

   To tell the framework to observe changes to the properties of an object or to the elements of an array, decorate the field with `@track`.

Refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators) for more details on decorators

I have done two changes to your JS file,

- Corrected the case of `recordId` variable
- Added `@track data`

Below code should work for you now:

```
import { api, LightningElement, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/GetContactCount.getContacts';
export default class AccountInfo extends LightningElement {
    @track data;
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getContacts , { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredRecordsMethod({ error, data }) {
        console.log('Hello'+data);
        if (data) {
            this.data  = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.data  = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hemant, i Copied as-is but no luck it didnt work. Console log is undefined.
 Not only that i created another LWC with simple query on account by passing its record id, yet its still not working.

Also i did the below blog copied as is still no luck:
https://www.codekiat.com/2020/04/how-to-pass-record-id-from-lightning-web-component-to-apex-controller.html#comment-form_8280374536221345217

not sure what i am missing here

Comment: Is the component on a record detail page?

Comment: Yes it is on record detail page. I am able to see the component no issues with that